# Representing the Empty Set in Redis Sets

Tags: java, redis

I have an application that is using Redis to cache query data from my relational database.

When I perform a fetch of the data, I first check the result cache in Redis, and if an entry exists in Redis I return that result.  Otherwise, if no cached result is found, I execute the query against the database and store the results into Redis.

I want to be able to cache empty results from the database as well.  What is the best way to represent an empty set in Redis, currently I am storing
a value of 0 into the database to represent the empty set:

```
Set<Integer> handleNullCaseSet = new HashSet<>();
        handleNullCaseSet.add(0);
```

Is there any better solution ?

Comment: are you creating a set for every record? Can you please your share sample data to understand the manner in which you are storing data in Redis?

Answer (score 2):

To represent an empty set in Redis, you need to use a sentinel value to represent the empty set, if the Redis set is empty, the key will be reclaimed.  Your solution is currently doing this using the value zero, there isn't a better way.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817865/redis-nil-or-empty-list-or-set) for more information.

Comment: In actual Quiz Master is doing same thing as per you said (using 0 as a sentinel value). He is looking for a better solution I guess.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear any solution has to use some kind of sentinel value .  Hoepfully that makes more sense.